I am having the "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified" when using MSAL in IOS
I am trying to test a .NET MAUI app on iOS using MSAL. It works fine on Android, but I am struggling to test the same app on iOS due to this error: "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified."
The app runs without issues on the iOS simulator after adding the com.microsoft.adalcache group in the entitlements.plistin the keychain section, but when I try to deploy the app to an iOS device, I get the error mentioned before.
From what I've read, this happens because the entitlements.plist is expected to match the provisioning profile. It seems there should be an option in Capabilities that says something like "KeyChain Sharing," but I can't find any capability referring to this in the Developer Portal.
If I remove the entitlements.plist, the app deploys fine on the device, but MSAL does not work, throwing the following error:
"The application does not have keychain access groups enabled in the Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to the iOS keychain.
The keychain access group '[Team].com.microsoft.adalcache' is not enabled in the Entitlements.plist.
I have tried both, using a developer profile or an adhoc distribution profile with the same result.
Any ideas are welcome.

Do you use Azure? Does it help? The keychain access group is not enabled

Thanks a lot for your comment. I have reviewed the post you propose, and everything was as described, so the problem persists.

Have you tried Manual provisioning for iOS apps

Yes, I have done it with manual provisioning for both the development and adhoc profiles. In both cases, it works as long as I don't include the entitlements.plist.

Have you followed the steps in iOS entitlements to use entitlements?

Finally, I managed to get it working! I’m not sure if the information I saw on other sites is incorrect or if Apple recently changed something, as several sources mentioned that the keychain-access-groups needed to be added to the entitlements.plist. I moved this key to the info.plist, and it finally worked!
